# Empty Dialogs in Flex Builder

Tags: eclipse, ide, flexbuilder

I have been experiencing a strange issue in Flex Builder 3 where certain dialogs such as the Add New Project wizard and the SVN Commit dialog are completely empty save for the title area.

I'm running Flex Builder v3.0 (build 3.02.2.214193) on the Windows 7 RC.  I have tried completely uninstalling and reinstalling Flex Builder to no avail.  I don't think it's Windows 7 causing the issues because it was working a couple of months ago with no problems.  Even more strange is that I have not installed any additional plugins or made any configuration changes to Flex Builder between the time before these problems began and now.

Has anyone else encountered this problem, and if so, know of any solutions?

Here are a couple of screenshots to illustrate the behaviour.

[alt text http://www.colincochrane.com/image.axd?picture=2009%2f9%2fdialog2.PNG](http://www.colincochrane.com/image.axd?picture=2009%2f9%2fdialog2.PNG)

[alt text http://www.colincochrane.com/image.axd?picture=2009%2f9%2femptydialog.png](http://www.colincochrane.com/image.axd?picture=2009%2f9%2femptydialog.png)

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing on Vista64 on a clean install of flexbuilder, specifically the Flex Build Path is blank, and the ant build properties dialog is blank.

Comment: honestly the best fix I found for it was to just install the flex builder 4 beta, it's free from fb3 owners and is a far superior development environment, fixed all my problems and builds are much much quicker.

Comment: The beta version is currently available at: http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/entitlement/index.cfm?e=labs_flashbuilder4
 FYI, Flash Builder is the new name for Flex Builder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this Adobe forums post](http://forums.adobe.com/message/997055), there are multiple causes:

1. SetPoint (as indicated by Scheea)
2. Wacom Tablet drivers

In addition, comments suggest the following:

1. UltraMon

These seem to suggest that the cause is any program which monitors keystrokes or mouse movement.

**Workaround:** In the new wizard dialog above, note the question mark on the bottom left (the help button).  When you click on the help button a help panel is added to the dialog on the right separated from the main dialog by a splitter.  When you drag the splitter the rest of the dialog appears. You may need to scroll to a position where you can see all of its contents, but it should become usable. Resizing the dialog alone was not sufficient for me.

In addition, I couldn't fully use the mouse to select elements so I had to type into the filter field in order for the correct projects to show up.

Answer (score 2):

You are probably running Logitech SetPoint. Try killing all setpoint processes. (you don't even have to restart flex). It worked for me :-S

Comment: If it's not SetPoint, look for other software that hooks into other apps' window messages. That could include:

- Other software that does keyboard/mouse remapping (like SetPoint)  
- Diagnostic/debugging tools related to window messages  
- Macro software that can record/playback key-presses and mouse clicks (like automated software testing suites)

Comment: I should add: I suspect that the underlying issue is that bad things happen when the kernel stack is running out of space (http://blogs.msdn.com/alejacma/archive/2009/08/11/controls-won-t-get-resized-once-the-nesting-hierarchy-of-windows-exceeds-a-certain-depth-x64.aspx) and all the hooked-in software is doing is causing a bit of extra memory use for each call.  If you _have_ to use a piece of software that hooks others' window messages, you could try other ways around the kernel stack exhaustion (switching to 32-bit windows, or switching to a later version with a bigger kernel stack)

Comment: Ultramon was the issue for me.

Comment: And upgrading to Ultramon 3.0.10 (from 2.7) resolved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the issue with Window7 x64 Ultimate with FB3 Pro and shutting down Set Point seems to have fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was Set Point and Display Fusion (allows you to set up multiple background images as wallpaper on multiple monitors). Took a lot of hair pulling to figure this out.